# Maintaining order of http requests within a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, mongoose

I am trying to save an array of objects in MongoDB using node.js express and mongoose (MEAN stack). However, when I make the http post requests on the front end for each item in the array, they don't show up on the back end in that order. Here's what I have on the front end:

```
$scope.postThenPost = function() {
    $http.post('/collection', $scope.doc).success(function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i<$scope.array.length; i++) {
            var req_obj = { thing: $scope.array[i] };
            $http.post('/collection2', req_obj);
        };
    };
};
```

and on the back end, express runs this for posting into /collection2:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var q = new q(req.body.thing);
    q.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(q);
        };
    });
};
```

Is there something I can do to ensure that the array goes in to the database in order? Thanks in advance

Comment: The $http.post is asynchonous by default. I recommend you posting the entire `$scope.array` to `/collection2`, then loop through the array on back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wasteful sending `$scope.array.length` number of HTTP requests when you have all the data you want to send ready.

Just post the whole array to your backend and then you can save them in a loop on the backend using something like `async` to guarantee the order.