# Make http requests in order / series

Tags: angularjs, promise

I built an array with jobs. Jobs are grouped by a start and end transaction. A transaction is a call to the webservice. An entire transaction can look like this:

1. Create Transaction (calls /opentransaction)
2. DoSomething A (calls /a)
3. DoSomething B (calls /b)
4. etc..
5. Close Transaction (calls /closetransaction)

My pseudo code looks something like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<jobs;i++)
{
  $http(job);
}
```

This works fine, but the order is random. I need to make sure that the order is maintained. How can enforce that?

Comment: By not using a loop, use function recursion instead. Note however that sending requests one at a time will obviously be slower than sending them in parallel.

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: Nope, sorry. someone else who cares to can, or you could find one of the other many questions on SO that are the same as this one.

Comment: You want a $promise to chain .then() and call each function in order. this is exactly what promises are for. Something like     return $q(function(resolve, reject) { 1.then(2).then(3).then(resolve) }

Comment: Here's a similar question with an out of the box solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332009/maintaining-order-of-http-requests-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript basically, don't do that, instead post the whole array in one request. Far better than posting `n` times.

Comment: If you call several times the remote service, how remote server knows what transaction should be used? If I open two tabs with same page, and click on submit on a short time, it will occurs. Try to make this like @KevinB saw.

Answer (score 2):

Store away the promise of your `$http` call and let the next job wait until the previous is done. This could look something like this:

```
var promise = $q.when(true);

for (var i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
  promise = promise.then(function () {
    return $http(job);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think looping is a good way of doing this, I would recommend using `$q` and just iterating through your tasks with a promise.

```
function myPromiseFunction() {
   return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
       doThingOne
          .then(doThing2)
          .then(doThing3)
          .then(doThing4)
          .then(resolve)
          .catch(function(error) {
               console.log("Error in my promise:", error);
          });
   });
}
```

The `doThing` are functions that do each of your desired behaviors so in your case the first thing would create the transaction, and return something to the next function if needed.

Comment: I don't know how many doThing functions I will have before hand.

Comment: @skone then you conditionally apply or curry or whatever you decide, you will still need the promise

Comment: @skone maybe if you clarify a bit further about what is determining the dynamic functions. I get what you are saying but I do not have enough information on how/why they are being generated and need to be run in order.

Comment: You can apply this same technique using a for loop.

Comment: to be fair, that's exactly what the other answer does. :)